# What is the sum of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {\arctan \dfrac{2}{{{n^2}}}}$ and why?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series 
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\arctan \dfrac{2}{{{n^2}}}}$$
converges because it is asymptotic to $\dfrac{2}{n^2}$ which is convergent.

What is its sum and why?

Comment: The sum seems to be extremely complicated, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28arctan%281%2Fn%5E2%29%29+from+n%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: But wolfram's answer suggests that it can be converted into a telescopic sum, in terms of the hyperbolic functions.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: not so much.  Instead, you can reduce the arctan to a difference of two arctans, but they do not telescope.  I will detail below when I have some time.

Comment: @RonGordon okay thanks. I will keep a watch.

Comment: 'tis a duplicate indeed, although I have a different approach than those shown.  I will document my approach either here or in the other venue.

Comment: Ah right. Voted to close as duplicate. This might get closed, so I will keep a watch on both.

Comment: OP has changed the question.  This one is a telescoping sum indeed.

Comment: @RonGordon yeah. Will you still post your alternate solution on the other thread?

Answer (score 6):

OK, now that you have changed the question...

$$\arctan{\frac{2}{n^2}} = \arctan{\frac1{n-1}} - \arctan{\frac1{n+1}}$$

so that the sum is

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan{\frac12} + \frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan{\frac13} + \arctan{\frac12}-\arctan{\frac14}+\cdots = \frac{3 \pi}{4}$$

Comment: Interesting how simply changing a $1$ to a $2$ makes everything so much simpler(even though I tend to assume that less constants *usually* mean less complications). Lesson in caution, if something looks simpler, it might be more complicated. +1

Comment: This is the same result I had using Mathematica...

Comment: But how to you deal with the 1/0 problem?

Comment: @Raffaele: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\arctan{\frac1{x}} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$