# How to find $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{n^{2}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider a sequence
$$ s_{n}=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{r^{2}} .$$

then we have

$$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{2}{r^{2}} \leq s_{n} \ \leq \sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{2}{r^{2}}
\\\Rightarrow \frac{\pi^{2}}{6} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}s_{n}\leq\frac{\pi^{2}}{3} $$

But how to attack to find the exact value of this limit? Anyone please?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/738284/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3053616/42969

Comment: @MartinR Of the three links, the last one I consider to be most applicable and is the one I chose as the question this post duplicates.  The first one, despite a superficial similarity (the only difference being $1/n^2$ instead of $2/n^2$), leads to a very different means of solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a hint:  $$\frac{2}{r^2} = \frac{2}{1 + (r^2 - 1)} = \frac{(r+1) - (r-1)}{1 + (r+1)(r-1)},$$ and $$\tan^{-1} \alpha - \tan^{-1} \beta = \tan^{-1} \frac{\alpha - \beta}{1 + \alpha \beta}.$$